# Is it possibe to view a forgotten admin password?

Tags: login, password-recovery

My ubuntu pc is setup to auto login, so since I never have to type my password, I've forgotten it.

Now, normally I'd just reset it, but I used that password for another online service, and I want to login on that service again but I don't know the password.

Is there any way to see my password? I'm logged in the admin account, it auto logins.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Ubuntu doesn't store password in plain text.. But I mean, I could be completely wrong.

Comment: You can reset password but not view it.

Answer (score 3):

The actual passwords are not stored, you can only find their hashes in `/etc/shadow`.

There is no easy way to recover passwords, your best try is to use a software like [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) to crack your password, but if you used a strong password, cracking it might take a very, very long time.

Answer (score 0):

> for another online service, and I want to login on that service again

The only option in retrieving your password would be to use the password recovery for that on-line service. I have yet to see one that does not offer one.